# ADB: "adb shell wm size" brings a "android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS " error on Oppo A94 5G

Tags: android, adb, android-11, screen-density

I am desperate a little to change the resolution on a not-rooted Oppo A94 5G with `Minimal ADB & Fastboot`. Same with an old LG G3 Mini works without problems.

But the A94 5G with Android 11 after the command:

```
adb shell wm size 1080x1440
```

I am getting the following error message:

```
Exception occurred while executing 'size': java.lang.SecurityException: Must hold permission android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS 
at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.setForcedDisplaySize(WindowManagerService.java:5719) 
at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerShellCommand.runDisplaySize(WindowManagerShellCommand.java:165) 
at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerShellCommand.onCommand(WindowManagerShellCommand.java:71) 
at android.os.BasicShellCommandHandler.exec(BasicShellCommandHandler.java:98) 
at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:44) 
at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.onShellCommand(WindowManagerService.java:1274) 
at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:936) 
at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:820) 
at android.view.IWindowManager$Stub.onTransact(IWindowManager.java:2872) 
at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.onTransact(WindowManagerService.java:1525) 
at com.android.server.wm.OppoWindowManagerService.onTransact(OppoWindowManagerService.java:185) 
at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1166) 
at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1130)
```

Is this a possible way to change the size (resolution) and the density on Android 11 devices?, or do I have to start further steps to get the right permissions to change the size? or is it another fundamental problem?

Answer (score 3):

In the meantime i found the reason for this permission problem.

To fix it, enable ""Disable Permission Monitoring" (English) / "Erlaubnisüberwachung deaktivieren" in the developer options of the phone.

After that the size command works fine.

Comment: Kudos for sharing the solution to your own question. This is the way! :-)

Comment: dont know what you mean exactly, how to fix the error i have written in my answer. But, this wholw "adb shell wm size" thing is obsolet, as there is no more overscan command enabled since Android 11, so it is nearly worthless, unfortunately.